# keep ajax content after press back button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, caching, back

I have a product page with infinite scroll pagination. More products are loaded with Ajax.

Like this: domain/books.

When the user clicks on a product it will go to the product page: domain/books/the_selected_book.html

When the browser back button is clicked, domain/books loads but not the the Ajax content.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that the previous page loads exactly as the user leaved it and in the same position, when back button is pressed on the new page.
Just like YouTube works.

I have searched the web without finding a good option to do this.
What is the best solution?

Comment: @Azametzin  Your scenario needs a clearer explanation. I would recommend setting up a stackblitz that uses mock data to demonstrate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
created_session = window.pageYOffset;
};
```

and in the product page just add this javascript code after loading ajax content. Also keep a variable that counts how many product loaded from database. For example 5 times new product added (12 for each for example). You should keep this in a session and multiply them 5*12 = 60. You can load the products from database by its limit property.

```
 if (isset? created session)
  window.scrollBy(0, created_session for pageYOffSet);
```